# Metadata for UX StackExchange

Tags: feature-request

Just wondering what metadata is collected or available for the forums (other than individual stats and general summaries), because it would probably help to answer many of the question on both the standard and meta forums. For example, I wouldn't mind seeing a frequency distribution of questions based on the number of votes they receive (or answers), and the average number of questions and answers that users ask. It gives better insight into areas that can be improved on, plus we get some quantitative figures which the users can probably help explain.

Answer (score 8):

I don't really understand how knowing things such as "*the average number of questions and answers that users ask*" would help with answering questions, as you seem to suggest, however there is a lot of data collected and available for querying. That's what the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/queries) is for. There are already hundreds of existing queries there that you can run, or you can create your own should you so desire.

Some example queries already written are:

- [How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag)
- [Find interesting unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions)
- [Low views, high votes yet unanswered](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/951/low-views-high-votes-yet-unanswered)

Have a look at existing queries there, or look at the [Data Explorer Help](http://data.stackexchange.com/help) if you wanted to compose your own.